# What type of adhesive do I use to bond metal & glass?

Tags: adhesive, table

I need some strong adhesive for a table. The glass panel fell off and I have no idea what type I need. It needs to be clear and very strong.

**Pics here:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm a newbie to the site and came across this post in luck! I have the EXACT same table as you and the same thing has happened to me. Just wanted to follow up on how well the epoxy stood up over time, and did you get a special one for metal?

Comment: Yeah, held no problem. I used this: http://www.screwfix.com/p/evo-stik-epoxy-rapid-2-x-15ml/76199

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J-B ClearWeld Quick Setting variety says it cures clear and sticks to metal and glass. I have never used this particular J-B product but I have had good results with other products of their line of epoxy.

Comment: @KeithDonegan any similar two part clear epoxy should do the trick. Just make sure you mix the parts **thoroughly** and act quickly, the stuff sets pretty quickly. I wouldn't touch the table for at least 24 hours, I've messed this up a few times by being impatient. Also, it usually smells pretty bad, so do it in a well ventilated area or be prepared to stink up the area you're applying it in!

Comment: [This to That](http://www.thistothat.com/cgi-bin/glue.cgi?lang=en&this=Metal&that=Glass) is usually a fairly good resource, or at least enough to get you started. Although in this case of glass to metal it doesn't give many recommendations.

Comment: Cheers guys, the epoxy did a cracking job. Strong as hell! Thanks  again.

Comment: Most epoxies have temperature dependent  cure rates.  If you have 5 minute epoxy, and need more time, cool both the epoxy and the surfaces by 10-20 degrees first.  Similarly 10 degrees to warm will shorten setting time drastically

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, I'd use a slow-setting 2-part epoxy.  Put some books on the center of the glass to apply some compressive force while waiting for the epoxy to cure.

Answer (score -2):

A U.V.-type cure glue should work. Although I have never used this type of glue Other persons have mentioned it works very well for bonding metal to glass. I believe that  you will need a specific light, that is an ULTRA VIOLET lamp to complete the adhesion process. Here is a link:  [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B015P21AII?keywords=uv%20glue&qid=1446526064&ref_=sr_1_8&sr=8-8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015P21AII)