# Attaching a towel hook to a glass shower door

Tags: bathroom, glass

We have a glass shower door. We have nowhere else to hang our towels in our tiny bathroom except on the back of the door. We've tried Command hooks, and we've tried using them with what we were told was an "industrial" adhesive for them, but they keep coming off.

What's the correct way to permanently attach a towel hook to tempered glass?

Comment: heat the glass and apply a large volume of hot glue, ensuring a perfect vacuum, coupling with the command hook backing. Trim excess with a razor. I've tested a 2.5lbs hook to hold 10lbs from a window w/o budging.

Comment: Answers go down there, @dandavis.

Answer (score 4):

You could use over door hooks, such as this, on the bathroom door.

Google `suction cup hooks` for hooks that attach to glass.

Supermagnet hooks are also available. You could attach a decorative metal plate to the bathroom door for them. Or use a supermagnet hook on one side of the glass door and an non-hook supermagent on the other side

[image]
[image]

---

EDIT:
Here is a link about attaching metal to glass.
[What type of adhesive do I use to bond metal & glass?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28745/what-type-of-adhesive-do-i-use-to-bond-metal-glass)

The accepted answer recommended epoxy.

Comment: The over-the-door style are hideously ugly, and the suction cups are even less reliable than the Command hooks.

Comment: Are you cleaning the glass first and buying quality products? Command hooks are pretty good.

Comment: added info to bottom of answer

Answer (score 3):

Your local auto parts store should have a simple kit for mounting rear view mirrors to windshield glass. It may be intended for metal, though, so choose your hooks carefully.

I'd also consider cyanoacrylate (super glue). Plan well.

Comment: I suspect those bonds aren’t intended to support a load more than the weight of a rear view mirror though. They seem like they’d be quite brittle.

Comment: Have you every tried to remove a mirror? :) I have little doubt that it would carry a towel (and the occasional clumsy bump) just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is a wall mounted towel rack with a swing arm(s), attached to the wall near the corner between the shower door and the wall.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=swing+arm+towel+rack&iax=images&ia=images

This would have the added benefit of quicker drying if you swing it out to 45 degrees when you're finished in the bathroom, thus allowing free air circulation on both sides of the towel.

Potentially, there are variations on this idea, such as a floor to ceiling pole with swing arms, or a swing arm unit that attaches to frame of the door or to the door jamb.